# Why am I getting a Seg-Fa

Tags: c

So I apologize for the general question. I haven't been able to find anything that speaks to my specific case. If there is something out there and I missed it, I'm sorry.

I am writing a function that reverses a string. It's for a project that comes with some pretty specific guidelines. I'm not allowed to use any functions such as malloc, printf etc and my function needs to return the string that  is passed in as an argument. The function needs to be prototyped as follows:

```
char *ft_strrev(char *str);
```

This is my funtction:

```
char *ft_strrev(char *str)
{
     int i;
     int j;
     char c;

     i = 0;
     j = ;
     c = '0';
     while(str[j] != '\0')
         j++;
     while(i != j)
     {
         c = str[i];
         str[i] = str[j];
         str[j] = c;
         i++;
         j--;
     }    
}
```

When I call this in a main and test it with putstr https://github.com/kigiri/userpref/blob/master/ft_42/ft_putstr.c it compiles fine, but at runtime I get a seg fault.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is "Seg-Fa"?

Comment: What's `j = ;`?

Comment: ` j = ;` Was ist das?

Comment: My money is on your calling this function with a read only string constant. Oops. But you didn't show us `main`.

Comment: Please post the version that compiles fine instead, and include the calling code with the variable declaration of the parameter passed to the function.

Comment: How do you call this function? Please create a [mcve] to show us. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The null terminator is also moving to the beginning of the new string. That can't be good.

Comment: You do not return anything.

Comment: `while(i != j)` and then `i++; j--;` if `j = 5` and `ì = 4`, next loop, `j = 4` and `i = 5`. The ending condition will never be reached and you can use `str[-1] = c; // Boom !`

Comment: @SouravGhosh Seg-Fa is the opposite to [Shangri-La](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shangri-La), a secret non-utopian valley in the Himalayas where everything is chaos and misery. It is the location to where all runaway code runs off. According to the legend, only truly worthy C programs with excessive use of `setjmp` may go there. Never to return (from subroutine) again.

Comment: *"it compiles fine"*?  I seriously doubt that.

Comment: Hi everyone. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. I'm so sorry for the lack of clarity and the j =; stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code (apart from this `j =;` stuff.

1. After the first `while` look j points to the `'\0'` after the end of the string rather than to the last character of the string.
2. Condition of the second look does handle the situation when `j - i` is odd initially.  for example, if `i` is `0` and `j` is `1` initially, then, after first iteration, `i` will be `1` and `j` will be `0`, so condition will still be true.

Here is fixed code:

```
char *ft_strrev (char *str)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (str [j] != '\0') j++;
    while (i < --j) {
        char t = str [i];
        str [i++] = str [j];
        str [j] = t;
    }    
    return str;
}
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks, looks like my comment was useful